# Flutter App on Ios without Mac with CodeMagic -- Apple Developer Program licence

Tags: ios, windows, flutter, macos, codemagic

I created a Flutter App on Windows and now I wanted to use it on IOS. Problem: I dont have a Mac so I used this website called codemagic.io. But when following to official [CodeMagic Tutorial](https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-build-and-distribute-ios-apps-without-mac-with-flutter-codemagic/)

the Tutorial said "You need to buy the Apple Developer Program licence to code sign and publish the app" Is this only to publish it on the App Store or also when I want to use it myself. So when creating the .ipa file, do I need it?
[Preparing your iOS project for code signing on your local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtR1B.png)
Later this comes up. Do I need to do that?

Thanks for all help :)

Comment: You need a developer program membership to install in a physical iOS device. You can use a free membership, but your app will need to be rebuilt and reinstalled every 7 days

Comment: Thank you :)
Can I get the free Membership over over the Apple Developer App. Is it still free?

Answer (score 0):

Per @Paulw11's comment you need to have at least a (free) Apple developer account to test on your own device. But having only a free Apple developer account places limits on the capabilities your app can have (see the [table on this page](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/reference/supported-capabilities-ios)) and may also place a time limit on the expiry of the provisioning profile but [as per this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/669516) its not clear if this is still the case as there appears to be no public information from Apple about that.
Finally [this page gives a summary of the differences](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/) between the free and paid accounts.